# Programatically access AEM Publish Server from Author AEM6.5

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, aem-6

We have a requirement in our application where we are building an utility which will only run on AEM author environment. This will search for users by his/her email ID on both author and publish servers. For this we have to connect to publish servers from author environment. I am trying to do it by using the following piece of code on author environment,

```
final String repoUrl = "http://localhost:4503/crx/server";
final javax.jcr.Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository(repoUrl);
final Session session = repository.login(new javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()), "crx.default");
```

But I am getting error while doing JcrUtils.getRepository(repoUrl) as below,

**Unable to access a repository with the following settings:
org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: http://localhost:4503/crx/server
The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:
Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.**.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I guess author and publish instances are not running on the same machine. You could check in the settings of the replication agent to get the right domain/ip of the publishers.

Comment: @Tushar- you can use 'Externalizer', it will give you complete URL based on the run mode / parameter you pass(ex:publish) https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-64/developing/platform/externalizer.html

Comment: @rajumuddana how externalizer will help in connecting to publish server, that only to get the proper url to connect to.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic both of the server are currently on the same machine

Comment: Please check if the publish instance has WebDAV enabled. It might have been disabled for security reasons. According to the JavaDoc of [JcrUtils#getRepository()](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html#getRepository-java.lang.String-) the implementation uses "spi2davex" to connect to the remote repository. [SPI2DAVex itself uses WebDAV](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.20/org/apache/jackrabbit/jcr2dav/package-summary.html).